# Gradle build error while building Qt app for android using androiddeployqt

Tags: android, qt, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Qt app for android which I command line building it using a shell script. I want to use gradle. So I am using the following command for the install step.

`androiddeployqt --sign mykey.keystore --storepass mypassword --output android-build --verbose --gradle --input MyApp/myapplib.so-deployment-settings.json`

I had trouble using gradle 2.2.1. Hence, I updated my gradle wrapper by downloading gradle 3.1. But while running the command gradle still seems to be trying to download 2.2.1 and gives the following error.

```
Pregenerating entry list for assets file engine.
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at     sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Abs    tractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:200)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1124)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Building the android package failed!
```

**Can someone please point out how can I get rid of this error & build my Qt app using gradle ?**

Comment: Browse to: `your_project/gradle/wrapper`, edit file gradle-wrapper.properties and make sure that "distributionUrl" points to the correct Gradle version you intend to use.

Comment: @ItaiGanot. Thanks for your attention. I have set to 3.1 already like so   -   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-bin.zip`   But, it still tries to get 2.2.1. Not sure why, is there some cache that needs to be cleared ? Or some way I can force a clean build ?

Comment: Yes, if you haven't explicitly set the variable "GRADLE_USER_HOME" then your gradle user home vy default is: `~/.gradle` (in linux/mac os) or `/Users/username/gradle` in Windows, browse there and delete the folder which is called "caches" then re-try, please let me know how it works for you.

Comment: I am on mac OS. I deleted `~/.gradle` folder. But it does not help. I have set the distribution url to 3.1 clearly. Now defined GRADLE_USER_HOME to an explicit folder to have finer control. But in vain !! And really strange.

Comment: In your project dir, run: `gradle wrapper`, let it generate new Gradle Wrapper files, then retry and let me know

Comment: AFAIK, `gradle wrapper` is executed on `gradle-3.1-all.zip` download from gradle.org. I did this. Got `gradlew, gradlew.bat, gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties & gradle-wrapper.jar` generated. Placed it inside MyQtApp/android folder. Ran the build from command line again. Got the same problem. This is truly amazing.

Comment: Following is what my `gradle-wrapper.properties` has:
    `distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-bin.zip`

But still gets the same error I have posted on my question !!

Comment: I read through https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html .. I think this is happening becuase my androidStudio is made to work with gradle 2.x. May be this is why it is forced to fetch gradle 2.x. But strange that it gets in the fetch errors. Working on fixing this. Thanks for the suggestion pointers until yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a network issue or a proxy issue. If gradle is not able to get through the proxy setting then create a `gradle.settings` in ~/.gradle or your own defined GRADLE_USER_HOME in PATH.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

### Windows

Set new variable "_JAVA_OPTIONS" in environment variables with following value

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=1234 -Dhttp.proxyPassword=5678 -Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUser=1234 -Dhttps.proxyPassword=5678
```

### Unix

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=1234 -Dhttp.proxyPassword=5678 -Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUser=1234 -Dhttps.proxyPassword=5678"
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st:** correct some invalid variables in QT's build settings/build environment (i.e. wrong slash was / instead of )... AND add some. Specifically:

```
ANDROID_HOME = D:\Android-SDK
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\Android-SDK
GRADLE_USER_HOME = C:\Users\pc\.gradle
JAVA_HOME = D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
```

(obviously these need to be upd for your install directories .i.e usually on C: drive)

Note: I specified these in Windows env settings, but it seems like they need to be specifically set in QT's env overrides.

**2nd:** remove the 29.0.0RC1 from Android SDK build-tools via Android Studio SDK manager. Apply.
Select 'show package details' to then be able to select the 28.0.3 version. Apply.

**3rd**: go into theQT project/app's folder and edit the gradle.properties file... change the line to:

```
androidBuildToolsVersion=28.0.3
```

Finally: you should probably should close and reopen QT and the project.

Answer (score 1):

as per the https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables

define environment variable **GRADLE_OPTS** with proxy for both http and https like this

```
GRADLE_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=123.23.23.123 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=123.23.23.123 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I have been troubled too by this lately:

> I updated my gradle wrapper by downloading gradle 3.1.
> But while running the command gradle still seems to be trying to download 2.2.1

It turns out that in older Qt versions (at least 5.5.1) androiddeployqt itself modifies the gradle version in your gradle.properties:

```
bool updateGradleDistributionUrl(const QString &path) 
{
    // check if we are using gradle 2.x
    GradleProperties gradleProperties = readGradleProperties(path);
    QString distributionUrl = QString::fromLocal8Bit(gradleProperties["distributionUrl"]);
    QRegExp re(QLatin1String(".*services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2..*.zip"));
    if (!re.exactMatch(distributionUrl)) {
        gradleProperties["distributionUrl"] = "https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip";
        return mergeGradleProperties(path, gradleProperties);
    }
    return true;
}
```